# Change display options on multiple products

Tags: product, layout, product-attribute, magento-1.6

I've been doing a lot of digging around to see if I could do this without using an extension without any luck.

Almost all of my products that have a product option live inside of 'container2' which is "Block after info column" but I want them to be in 'container1' which is "Product info column".

How do I change all of the products to be in "Product info column" without going through every single product or using an extension?

[image: product design field]

Answer (score 1):

Create yourself a set-up script that builds a collection of all the products you want to change.

Then loop through these products and set `options_container` to the value `container1`.

```
foreach($productCollection as $product) {
     $product->setOptionsContainer('container1');
     $product->getResource->saveAttribute($product, 'options_container');
}
```

This should then save the value on all products in your collection.